# Connect from Java app to Google Cloud Bigtable which running on Docker

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to connect to Google Cloud Bigtable which running on Docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8086:8086 -v ~/.config/:/root/.config \
bigtruedata/gcloud-bigtable-emulator
```

It starts without any problems:

```
[bigtable] Cloud Bigtable emulator running on 127.0.0.1:8086
```

`~/.config` it is my default credentials that I configured in this way:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

I used Java-code from official sample [HelloWorld](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-hello).
Also, I changed connection configuration like this:

```
Configuration conf = BigtableConfiguration.configure("projectId", "instanceId");

conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_HOST_KEY, "127.0.0.1");
conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_PORT_KEY, "8086");
conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_USE_PLAINTEXT_NEGOTIATION, "true");

try (Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(conf)) {
    ...
```

And I set `BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:8086` environment variable in a configuration for my app in IntelliJ Idea.

But when I run my Java app, it gets stuck on `admin.createTable(descriptor);` and shows this log:

> ... 
>   16:42:44.697 [grpc-default-executor-0] DEBUG
>   com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.Recycler
>   - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8

After some time it shows log about `BigtableClientMetrics` and then throws an exception:

> java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

I get the same problem when trying to run Google Cloud Bigtable with my own Dockerfile.

---

When I run Google Cloud Bigtable with this command:

```
gcloud beta emulators bigtable start
```

my app completed successfully.

So, how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Now I have this exception:

> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for unknown reason

and before this another exception is thrown:

> java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658118/when-is-java-io-ioexceptionconnection-reset-by-peer-thrown), they explain with many cases when the `Connection reset by peer` error appears.

Comment: Hi Daria, do you know if you opened the network in the docker container to access that port? Sometimes containers will not allow all connections by default, both in the docker level and the image level (i.e.: iptables).