# Bigtable Emulator & Google Discovery Resource with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

I am trying to use bigtable emulator within `googleapiclient.discovery.Resource` module of python.

- Bigtable emulator run on `127.0.0.1:8086`

Bigtable Client service setup via discovery service:

```
http = httplib2.Http(None, timeout=http_timeout)
client=discovery.build('bigtableadmin', 'v2', http=_http)
_client._baseUrl = 127.0.0.1:8086
```

Following post request is sent by discovery:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8086/v2/projects/my_project/instances/my_instance/tables?alt=json
```

which eventually returns `[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer.`

I can utilise bigtable emulator with using `google.cloud.bigtable.Client` without any problem.

I can use local pubs emulator with same discovery service, and rest api seems to work fine but fails on bigtable emulator.

Does Bigtable Emulator supports post requests? Or emulator has limited usage with only `google.cloud.bigtable.Client`? I could not find any detail on emulator documentation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the way your are Using the Resource class? adding a code snippet with an specific method for a sample execution would be good to narrow down and follow replications.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I added discovery service build. Same approach works with pubsub emulator and service client can send rest api calls to the emulator. But it does not work on bigtable. I started to think that bigtable emulator does not support rest api operations.

Comment: I've found a couple of entries with a similar behavior, and I would say that the problem relies on the way that the Discovery library is managing the connection. I've tried with curl and I got quite the same error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658118/when-is-java-io-ioexceptionconnection-reset-by-peer-thrown
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839322/connect-from-java-app-to-google-cloud-bigtable-which-running-on-docker

Comment: I saw them. my guess is bigtable emulator does not support REST api calls. @sergiofranco

Comment: from the docstring of `google.cloud.bigtable.Client`: "note:: Since the Cloud Bigtable API requires the gRPC transport, no ``_http`` argument is accepted by this class."

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment done above and as described [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/1.1.0/client.html), since the Cloud Bigtable API requires the gRPC transport, no _http argument is accepted by this class.

Therefore, this would explain the error that your get