# flink in 1.17.1 jobmanger raise java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: apache-flink

I started a Flink cluster on k8s and did not run tasks, but jobmanager reported this error every other time, and taskmanager did not print any errors

```
2023-08-31 16:17:47,118 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.files.StaticFileServerHandler [] - Caught exception
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [flink-dist-1.17.1.jar:1.17.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_372]
2023-08-31 16:17:51,196 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.legacy.files.StaticFileServerHandler [] - Caught exception
```

I haven't seen any issues causing it yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is "java.io.IOException:Connection reset by peer" thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658118/when-is-java-io-ioexceptionconnection-reset-by-peer-thrown)